# Autorestart application if cpu load is over 40% and keep looping unit it drops

Tags: windows, powershell, vlc

I made a powershell script where the program is being killed if the cpu load goes over 40%.

This is the code:

```
$procname = 'vlc'
$cpu_usage=40
$logfile = 'C:\HighCPU.log'
Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process -Filter "Name like'$procname%' and PercentProcessorTime > $cpu_usage" | 
% {
"{0} - killing process {1} ID {2} cpu usage: {3}" -f (Get-Date), $procname,$_.IDProcess, $_.PercentProcessorTime | Out-File -Append $logfile 
kill $_.idprocess
}
```

I want to make this code loop until the CPU load for this certain procname is below 40. Than the script needs to exit. The interval of the check can be dynamic/adjustable. Say 5 seconds.

Also if possible I was wondering how i can make it check more than one procname.

The logfile is there to log the situation but actually is obsolite.

Comment: This is powershell, why did you tag batch?

Comment: I removed Powershell from the title as it was suggesting you wanted to kill the powershell process. That and tags are usually redundant in titles.

Comment: I added batch because maybe there was a solution to do it in a batch file only.